# Programmatically disable content translation options in content edit form

Tags: 8, forms

I want to **programmatically** disable the content translation options located at the bottom of the content edit form (see yellow area in screenshot):
[image]

I know that i can disable the revision information options with the following code in a form_alter hook:

```
$form['revision_information']['#access'] = false; // <--- works
```

But that doesn't work with the translation options, at least with what I tried:

```
$form['content_translation']['#access'] = false; // <--- doesn't work
```

So ideally, how can i disable the whole yellow area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access to `content_translation` property in the `hook_form_alter` but you can do it in after_build callback.

> after_build: runs after the form or element is built for display.

Try with the following:

1. Add `#after_build` to the form:

```
 
/**
 *Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_YouContentType_edit_form') {
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'myModule_after_build';
  }
}
```

2. Implement your after_build function

```
    function myModule_after_build($form, &$form_state){
      $form['content_translation']['#access'] = FALSE;
      return $form;
    }
```

Comment: i'm glad that help! :)